# vector::push_back using std::move for internal reallocations

Tags: c++, move

A type `X` has a non-trivial move-constructor, which is *not* declared noexcept (ie. it can throw):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>


struct X {
    X()=default;
    X(X&&) { std::cout << "X move constructed\n"; } // not 'noexcept'
    X(const X&) { std::cout << "X copy constructed\n"; }
};

struct test {
    X x;
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<X> == false);
    static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<test> == false);

    std::vector<test> v(1);
    v.push_back(test{}); // internal object re-allocation, uses copy-constructor
}
```

When calling `push_back` on a `vector<test>`, internal reallocations cause existing objects to be copied, which is expected.
The output is:

```
X move constructed
X copy constructed
```

Apparently, the second line is related to internal object reallocation.

Now an unrelated `std::unique_ptr<int>` is added to `test`:

```
struct test {
    std::unique_ptr<int> up;
    X x;
};
```

The output becomes:

```
X move constructed
X move constructed
```

Why is internal reallocation using the move-constructor this time ?
Technically, `X(X&&)` can still throw an exception; wouldn't that violate the strong exception guarantee of `push_back` ?

compiler is gcc 11.2.1 and/or clang 12.0.1

Comment: `emplace_back`'s strong exception guarantee is revoked if an element's move constructor throws. It will only use a non-noexcept move constructor if it absolutely has to, it prefers a copy constructor to a potentially throwing move constructor specifically to avoid having to break this guarantee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [[vector.modifiers]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/vector.modifiers#2) if the element type of `std::vector` is not copy-insertable and not nothrow-move-constructible, then an exception thrown from a move constructor of the element type results in an unspecified state of the container.

`std::vector` must prefer the copy constructor if the type isn't nothrow-movable, so that the exception guarantees can be preserved, but if that isn't possible, it is impossible to give strong exception guarantees.

Comment: So much for strong guarantees huh.. IMO, it should have rejected the code, but I'm not in the committee. Thanks for the answer.